# How to set a eos contract on jungle network

Tags: smart-contract, cleos, ram

As I trying to deploy a contract on Eos Jungle test network using cmd. But I failed to run.

**Command :**

```
cleos --url https://jungle3.cryptolions.io:443 set contract tulsipadalia addressbook -p awsdwesasw12
```

**Error :**

```
Error 3080001: Account using more than allotted RAM usage
Error Details:
account tulsipadalia has insufficient ram; needs 160569 bytes has 5487 bytes
```

Can anyone add a reference for the same?

Comment: This question has already been answered, check the other answer in order to get your solution